# how to store byte arrays using Jedis

Tags: redis, jedis

I am using **Redis** and its java interface **Jedis** but I am having a problem of how can I hold a list of byte arrays, i had seen set but it works for string only and when I try to create a list an add a byte array it works but when I am trying to add another byte array to that list I get an exception, how can I solve that?

thanks in advance.

code:

```
  byte[] data = {12,23,45,67,127};
          byte[] data2 = {13,25,46,68,121,44};
          String id = "xyzd12";
          jedis.lpush(id.getBytes(),data);
          jedis.rpush(id.getBytes(),data2);
```

when I run that code I get an exception of:  `redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value`

Comment: Can you please add your code? It's hard to debug otherwise

Comment: I have added sample code

Comment: Well just use methods that accept bytearrays. Jedis extends BinaryJedis AFAIK.

Comment: how can I do that? I am new to this please add some links!

Comment: @flashdisk I can't reproduce your bug! When I run your code, everything is normal. What version of jedis do you use? Did you post the whole code?

Comment: your are totally right it is my bad!, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

That error message means that you try to do something on wrong data type.
ie, you try to do list operation on key `id.getBytes()` but `id.getBytes()` is not a list type. It seems that your redis instance already have that key and it is not a list.

```
# redis.c
shared.wrongtypeerr = createObject(REDIS_STRING,sdsnew("-WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value\r\n"));

# t_list.c
if (lobj && lobj->type != REDIS_LIST) {
   addReply(c,shared.wrongtypeerr);
   return;
}
```